# Birt Conditional Page Break

Tags: eclipse, birt, maximo

I'm designing a BIRT report that should print on a form. In this report it is printing in both sides so the client is asking to do a Page Break if the details of a WorkOrder ends in a odd number so both WorkOrders wouldnt be in the same sheet.

Is it possible to add a pagecount() and do a page break if it is the end of the work order an its an odd number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I only have part of the answer. It would be possible on the adding pagination in the beforeFactory on the ReportDesign section. Out of the box Maximo reports have a pagination statement for PDF's. You can extend the if statement - see example of OOTB code below.

You would need to be able to bring back the WO number as a global parameter. That part is what you would need to do some additional research on.

```
if ( (reportContext.getParameterValue("usepagebreaks") == "false")|| reportContext.getOutputFormat() == "pdf" ) {
// Give each table in the report a name, and add the names to the list below, e.g. ["mainTable", "childTable1"]
var tableListing = ["dataSet_inventory_id13#"];
for each(var tableName in tableListing) {
    var table = reportContext.getReportRunnable().designHandle.getDesignHandle().findElement(tableName)
    if (table != null) {
        table.setProperty("pageBreakInterval", 0);
    }
}
```

}